# Loop through multiple TD, grab multiple values, fill array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two tables on the page.
Inside of my second table I am dynamically adding html from JS.
I am checking to see if the `<tr>` inside of the `tbody` are empty using:

```
var rowCount = $('#dynatable >tbody >tr').length;
```

If the row count is 0 I continue on with my javascript, if 1 or more `<tr>` exists I need to go through each `<tr>` and grab the two input values inside the `<td>`; for every `<tr>` available. Then need to collect the data into an array for server-side processing.

```
<table id="dynatable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="p_scents">
    <tr><td class="ts_td"><input type="text" name="ts_value[]" class="timestamp_input"/></td><td><TEXTAREA NAME="ts_description[]" class="ts_desc" rows="3" cols="30"  style="resize:none;" ></TEXTAREA></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="ts_td"><input type="text" name="ts_value[]" class="timestamp_input"/></td><td><TEXTAREA NAME="ts_description[]" class="ts_desc" rows="3" cols="30"  style="resize:none;" ></TEXTAREA></td></tr>
</tbody>
```

I have browsed similar questions but I cannot figure out a solution for my situation. I had a previous solution using simpleHTMLDOM + PHP but it's way too slow performance wise.

I was told to use JS or jquery and I am quite unfamiliar with both, any help is greatly appreciated.
How do I grab the values of multiple inputs from multiple `<tr>`'s inside a specific table and store the values in an array?

Comment: can form encode it by simply wrapping table in `<form>` and using `serialize()`

Comment: I will look into serialize(), thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your classes will be the same, you could do something like this with jQuery.

It put the values into arrays.

```
var values = $("input[class='timestamp_input']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();

var textAreaValues = $("textarea[class='ts_desc']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();

console.log(values);

console.log(textAreaValues);
```

JSFiddle demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/donal/h7exhLw9/2/).

Comment: Yes the classes will be the same name so this will work.
Thank you for the solution.